# Can't find how to get Access Token after login Auth0

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to log in a user. The first time the user logs in I receive a json response that has the access_token and ID token.

**I want to save this so I can use the access token to hit one of my APIs.**

I can't find which method is calling xxxx.auth0.com/oauth. If I can find that method and save the response in my cookies, that'd be great. (Unless I'm not supposed to do that).

I have also tried finding a way to get an access token, but I don't see how that's possible. I'm having a hard time with the documentation.

The other problem I'm having a hard time with as well is whenever the user logs back in or refreshes the page. No access token is given to me. I don't even see the network response for xxxx.auth0.com/oauth. Security isn't my strongest suit. But I was hoping Auth0 could relieve some of the burden.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';
import Auth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js/dist/typings/Auth0Client';
import { from, of, Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError, concatMap, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  // Create an observable of Auth0 instance of client
  auth0Client$ = (from(
    createAuth0Client({
      domain: "XXXXX.auth0.com",
      client_id: "JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXG",
      redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}` + `/home`
    })
  ) as Observable<Auth0Client>).pipe(
    shareReplay(1), // Every subscription receives the same shared value
    catchError(err => throwError(err))
  );
  // Define observables for SDK methods that return promises by default
  // For each Auth0 SDK method, first ensure the client instance is ready
  // concatMap: Using the client instance, call SDK method; SDK returns a promise
  // from: Convert that resulting promise into an observable
  isAuthenticated$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.isAuthenticated())),
    tap(res => this.loggedIn = res)
  );
  handleRedirectCallback$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.handleRedirectCallback())), tap(res => { console.log(res); })
  );


  // Create subject and public observable of user profile data
  private userProfileSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject$.asObservable();
  // Create a local property for login status
  loggedIn: boolean = null;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  // When calling, options can be passed if desired
  // https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#getuser
  getUser$(options?): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getUser(options))),
      tap(user => {
        this.userProfileSubject$.next(user);
      })
    );
  }


  localAuthSetup() {
    // This should only be called on app initialization
    // Set up local authentication streams
    const checkAuth$ = this.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      concatMap((loggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (loggedIn) {
          // If authenticated, get user and set in app
          // NOTE: you could pass options here if needed
          return this.getUser$();
        }
        // If not authenticated, return stream that emits 'false'
        return of(loggedIn);
      })
    );
    checkAuth$.subscribe();
  }

  login(redirectPath: string = '') {
    // A desired redirect path can be passed to login method
    // (e.g., from a route guard)
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log in
      client.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}` + `/home`,
        appState: { target: redirectPath }
      });
    });
  }

  handleAuthCallback() {
    // Call when app reloads after user logs in with Auth0
    const params = window.location.search;
    if (params.includes('code=') && params.includes('state=')) {
      let targetRoute: string; // Path to redirect to after login processsed
      const authComplete$ = this.handleRedirectCallback$.pipe(
        // Have client, now call method to handle auth callback redirect
        tap(cbRes => {
          // Get and set target redirect route from callback results
          targetRoute = '/home';
        }),
        concatMap(() => {
          // Redirect callback complete; get user and login status
          return combineLatest([
            this.getUser$(),
            this.isAuthenticated$
          ]);
        })
      );
      // Subscribe to authentication completion observable
      // Response will be an array of user and login status
      authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {
        // Redirect to target route after callback processing
        this.router.navigate([targetRoute]);
      });
    }
  }

  logout() {
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log out
      client.logout({
        client_id: "JxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxG",
        returnTo: `${window.location.origin}`
      });
    });
  }
}
```

If I subscribe to auth0client I can see the token. But I am not able to access it do to cache being private.

```
  console.log(data.cache.cache["default::openid profile email"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. And I agree that person feels lost while getting mind through Auth0 SPA sdk as there is no clear property or function to get access token.

You can get access token by calling getTokenSilently() method of Auth0Client.

For easiest way following method could be added in Auth service to set access token and this method could be called right after login. (this might not be very good idea but will help you understand the flow.)

```
setAccessToken() {
  this.auth0Client$.subscribe(async (client: Auth0Client) => {
    this.AccessToken = await client.getTokenSilently();});   
}
```

You can also add observable method in authService and call this observable from anywhere (for instance http interceptor to add access token in header of calling api)

```
getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
   return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
   concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options))));
}
```

one of the best example I found to get access token and use it with http interceptor to add it to header of http call is [enter link description here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-calling-an-api)

Comment: Honestly, what I'm doing is using hooks. So after a user registers, auth0 sends the users authid and email and I store it into my DB. Auth0 has to send a secret key as to ween out bots or anyone else who isn't Auth0. Then if a user wants to perform CRUD actions they send the email and authID and I validate that.